# .save() function doesn't work in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to write a function that updates the score of the user using node.js and mongoose.

Here is my code:

```
router.post('/submitScore', (req, res) => {
    totalScore = Number(req.body.winnerScore) + Number(req.body.loserScore);
    // TODO: submit the score and redirect to another page
    User.find({teamName: req.body.winnerName}, (err, winner) => {

        // TODO: add special bonus for winner!
        winner.score = (winner.score / totalScore) * 100;
        winner.save((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        });
    })
    // TODO: add loser function
    console.log(typeof Number(req.body.winnerScore))
    res.redirect('/admin/');
});
```

I face with the following error:

> ```
>   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>   ^
> ```
>
> TypeError: winner.save is not a function

**Note** Whenever I console.log(winner), it prints the following

```
[ { score: 0,
_id: 5b963ef5c20ed241b87813bf,
teamName: 'mostafa',
faculty: 'مهندسی کامپیوتر',
email: 'm@m.ir',
password: '$2b$10$OqqagG.cwLE4RpGEn8voBOsHCRENgbivOejK9xmwdQ.TCAaVrYf0u',
__v: 0 } ]
```

but winner.score returns undefined where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **findOne** and then **save**

```
User.findOne({teamName: req.body.winnerName}, (err, winner) => {
      if(winner) //also check exists.
        // TODO: add special bonus for winner!
        winner.score = (winner.score / totalScore) * 100;
        winner.save((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        });
       } else {
//return not exists.
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not check the err variable or the result of the find method; it looks like he can not found that entry in your database and therefore throws an error

Edit: After the updated post it looks like you try to call the save method on an array; so in order for your app to work you have to get the first element of the find for example:

```
winner = winner[0];
```

Or change your query to findOne() instead of find() if you are sure you will always just expect one result:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne

Answer (score 1):

Notice how `winner` is an array, not an object, as indicated by the brackets (`[ ... ]`) surrounding it.

Use `findOne` instead of `find` if you're sure that the query will yield at most one result (also, don't assume that because you don't get an error, `winner` will be defined: if the query was succesful but didn't yield any results, `winner` will be `null`).

Comment: I give you upvote, I would be thankful if you can give me upvote, too. because I'm blocked now :( .